# Chrome custom tabs's close button feature override

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

Close button of "chrome custom tab" close the entire webview itself. However I want it to override its behaviour to work as hardware back button behaviour so that user can go back to previous page of web instead of closing webview.

I read so many posts and blogs but i could not get find any solution. I have found the solution to change the close button icon.

Answer (score 2):

In my case my application does nothing but open the Chrome Custom Tab, so I was able to do this:

```
// This is called on boot, and when the Chrome Custom Tab's X button in the top left is clicked.
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    tryLaunch();
}
```

where `tryLaunch` launches Chrome

Comment: If application does something rather than just opening the Chrome Custom Tab, then this little checking on 'onResume()' will be helpful. Refs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41035189/4784634

Answer (score 0):

That's not currently possible.