# Callback on dismiss of chrome custom tabs

Tags: android, android-activity, chrome-custom-tabs

I have an activity 'A' and inside that activity, I have opened a chrome custom tab. Now when the user closes the chrome custom tab I want to open another activity 'B'. Is there a way to know when the chrome custom tabs has been closed. Or any other way to solve the above problem.

Comment: Please refer the below link, It is not a concrete solution but might help to some one. https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-android/issues/24

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could keep track that Custom Tabs was opened on a boolean variable on Activity A.

```
private boolean mCustomTabsOpened = false;

public void launchCustomTabs(String url) {
   mCustomTabsOpened = true;
   new CustomTabs.Builder().build().launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
}
```

Then, use Activity A's `onResume()` to launch Activity B

```
public void onResume() {
    if (mCustomTabsOpened) {
        mCustomTabsOpened = false;
        startActivity(this, ActivityB.class);
    }
}
```

You may want to use the KeepAliveService to prevent ActivityA from being destroyed, as illustrated [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsclient/MainActivity.java#L190)

Comment: I think this is the correct link (the file has changed since this was posted): https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/a9f1a9b6cb4b52df31aba79813029afec4f570e0/Application/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsclient/MainActivity.java#L190

Answer (score 43):

In Activity A you launch the Chrome Custom Tab like this:

```
private final int CHROME_CUSTOM_TAB_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

public void launchCustomTabs(String url) {
    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
    customTabsIntent.intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivityForResult(customTabsIntent.intent, CHROME_CUSTOM_TAB_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

And in onActivityResult your check for that request code:

```
if (requestCode == CHROME_CUSTOM_TAB_REQUEST_CODE) {
    startActivity(this, ActivityB.class);
}
```

Comment: as for android 31 doesn't work onActivityResult is called as soon as the customtab open and is never called on its dismiss

Comment: I have target API 34, using `rememberLauncherForActivityResult( ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult() )` and it is called on close, not on open. so working well

Answer (score 1):

well, this doesn't work, because it's not possible as per now to track the closing of chrome custom tab, if you are trying to call or display a dialog box on hit of back button, i.e., to ask for a confirmation.
Well you can handle them over your activity (which is launching it at the first place) but that's not what you want i think.
But if anyone does find the solution then please comment below.