# Callback from Custom Tab

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-studio, chrome-custom-tabs

I have one activity, in which i have opened one url in to custom tab.
Is there any way to get callback from Custom Tab?
Opened the url in Custom Tab and wants the callback from that url.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010017/callback-on-dismiss-of-chrome-custom-tabs)?

Comment: Yes,but it's not appropriate answer. @Piyush

Comment: Are you able to know then your url completely loaded? If you'r then you can use interface or you can simply call child activity using _startActivityForResult_

Comment: No, i just want the call back url same as webview gives to us.Like in Webview we are using Webview Client to get call back url.In webview there is a method named shouldOverrideUrlLoading gives us call back from browser. So, is there any way to get call back from Custom Tab. @Piyush

Comment: getting result in onActivityResult after i press back, not automatically.

Comment: Okay so do you want that when you url loaded in tabs after that should it automatically close with some callback as webviewClient does for _pageFinished_?

Comment: I have to use custom tabs instead of webview, because webview can't able to handle a webpage that contains social login.Please help me out in this. @Piyush

Comment: Yes sure i will help you. !Okay so do you want for _customTab_ that when you url loaded in tabs after that should it automatically close with some callback as webviewClient does for pageFinished?

Comment: Yes, exactly what you understand. @Piyush

Comment: Yeah. I think this is what you need [check](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Chrome-Custom-Tabs)

Comment: I have to develop a demo with Pinterest login. As pdk is now deprecated, i have to use OAuth to develope a demo.I have opened that url in custom tab, but custom tab is not giving me call back after successful login.Thanks in advance.

Comment: As i know that with custom tab user need a user interaction for closing tab. You can implement broadcast receiver and also as i said earlier to use both options.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795847/how-to-close-chrome-custom-tabs?rq=1) is the best way to do close tab automatically. CustomTab doesn't provide any callback which indicate that you'r url has been loaded completely and you get call back. Sure you will not. Without user interaction it is not possible. If you want to close automatically then i have mentioned link in my comment!

Comment: Ok, let me try. Thanks

Comment: Okay. try it and give feedback.

Comment: NOT WORKING AT ALL!!! @Piyush

Comment: Have you done same thing as mentioned in code?

Comment: I have done same as posted on that answer, but didn't get call back in broadcast receiver.

Comment: Okay. No issue. I will post solution

Comment: Yes, please as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately No! 
The custom chrome tabs are part of Chrome browser and need chrome browser to be installed on the target device as they use the same activity. But You have few alternative options to get the control back to your app -

1. Implement a custom deeplink your app recognizes and the Url which is opened in the chrome tabs loads that deeplink when it finishes its work and needs to close itself. The deeplink when loaded by the chrome tab, will fire an intent which could be accepted by either the chrome browser or your app only. The user will get the choices to choose one from. But this mechanism is possible only if you have server side control of the web page you are trying to load in the chrome tabs.
2. Let the user close the chrome tab by himself by clicking on the back arrow button or an action button you could add while building the Chrome tabs intent.
3. Use webview inplace of Chrome tabs and get control of the entire web experience. But with this full control will come greater responsibilites too, as via webview you can easily intercept user's data, ignore his clicks or redirect him anywhere. If its your own website or a some local web content you need to display, go with webview, else go with chrome tabs.

Have a look at this [example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/demos/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsdemos/CustomUIActivity.java) to get an idea of what could be customized with the custom tabs.

Comment: I don't wants to use deep linking. Is there any way to get callback?

Comment: I'm afraid no :(

Comment: Implemented with Deep Linking.Is there any way to open my app directly?Because there is two option available either crome or in app.How can i open my app directly without showing that popup either app or crome? Thanks in advance. @rupesh

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to ambiguation dialog below API level 23. At API level 23 and above, you can use app linking 
- https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0#app-linking